# Estou consumindo uma API com basic authentication oauth e retorna: Solicitação incorreta (400)

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth

Fala, galera!

Seguinte, desenvolvi uma api no spring boot e já testei com o postman e esta funcionando normalmente, a segurança dela é uma autenticação com oauth bem basico. Agora estou testando em uma aplicação em c# que tenho aqui para retornar o token para poder consumir os endpoint, contudo quando estou fazendo a chamada para retornar o token esta me retornando:

```
"System.Net.WebException: 'O servidor remoto retornou um erro: (400) Solicitação Incorreta.'"
```

Segue o código abaixo:

```
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:8080/oauth/token");
        req.Method = "POST";

        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("apisustentacao:HHednf8iwFgre$$$@"));
        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

No postman esta funcionando normalmente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue abaixo mais imagem do Header do postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agradeço quem puder me ajudar

Comment: Você desenvolveu uma API Rest? Poderia postar as outras imagens do Postman mostrando os Headers, Body, Parametros?

Comment: O erro 400 indica que a solicitação chegou ao server e foi processada, mas alguma coisa enviada não estava correta. Você tentou capturar o Response do WebException e verificar o que ele diz? Seria essa mensagem que você colou o Response?

Comment: Sim esta é a mensagem

Comment: adicionei mais print do postman @PedroPaulo